# How can we write into a text field after taking input from it in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

The idea is, if  the first textbox is fed a number and the checkbox is checked the second textbox displays the square of the the number, and when the second textbox is fed a number then the first textbox displays the square root of the number

```
function myFunction() {
  var sq = document.getElementById("square");
  var tf1 = document.getElementById("text1");
  var tf2 = document.getElementById("text2");
  alert(sq.checked+tf1.value+tf2.value);
  if(sq.checked==true){
    if(tf1.value!=""){
      tf2.value = tf1*tf1;
    }
    else if (tf2.value!=""){
      tf1.value = Math.sqrt(tf2);
    }
  }
}


/// Here is the html

<input type="text" id="text1"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="square"> square </input>
<input type="text" id="text2"/>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
```

the code isn't working either way

Comment: okay so how do you call the function? what is the html?

Comment: FYI: An input's value is a string and will not be null.

Comment: still not working

Answer (score 2):

You are doing the arithmetic on the DOM objects, not on their values. Like this:

```
tf1*tf1
```

... should be:

```
tf1.value*tf1.value
```

The same goes for `Math.sqrt(tf2)`: should use `tf2.value`.

#### Some other remarks:

- You don't need to add `===true` when verifying a boolean value. You can just do:

  ```
    if(sq.checked){
  ```
- Don't use `alert` to debug. Use `console.log` instead. BTW: the console has lots of features to help debugging.
- I am not sure what the intended behaviour is, but I think you maybe want to have your `if ... else` structure/nesting differently. Maybe like below:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var sq = document.getElementById("square");
  var tf1 = document.getElementById("text1");
  var tf2 = document.getElementById("text2");
  console.log(sq.checked, tf1.value, tf2.value);
  if(sq.checked){
    if(tf1.value!=""){
      tf2.value = tf1.value*tf1.value;
    }
  } else if (tf2.value!=""){
    tf1.value = Math.sqrt(tf2.value);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text1"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="square"> square </input>
<input type="text" id="text2"/>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice I will remember it next time.

Answer (score 0):

Couple little things here to point out before we get to the meat of it. Your variable names are pretty poor. Rather than shorten things with abbreviations that only you know the meaning of and that you will have to convert in your head every time you read, it is a better practice to use descriptive variable names. They will get shortened by a minifier before they go into production, so shortening like this only hurts readability with no benefit, so I changed that.

Next, you did checks like this that leaves your intent ambiguous:

```
 if(sq.checked==true) { ... }
```

If you are using loose equality (`==`) to check if something can be cast to true (rather than strong equality (`===`) to test if something is actually contains the boolean `true`) then you can do this instead:

if (sq.checked) { ... }

Same principle here, where you do a null check:

```
 if(tf1.value!=null){ ... }
```

That can just be written like this:

```
 if(tf1.value){ ... }
```

Beyond being shorter syntactically, in this particular case it is also a logic error because an empty string will never be loosely equal to null.

Since you are having to use the value of the fields multiple times, it would be a good idea to cache those values in local variables at the top of the function.

The main issue that you are having though is that you are doing math on the pointer to the field rather than the field's value. I also took out the alert because I assumed you had that there as a test. Most people use console.log() to rest values rather than alert. To see the console, do a right click and inspect the page and then go to Console, which is a live JavaScript interpreter. CTRL + SHIFT + I is the keyboard shortcut in Chrome.

So here is the updated code:

```
function myFunction() {
  var squareNumCbx = document.getElementById('square'),
      txtField1 = document.getElementById('text1'),
      txtField2 = document.getElementById('text2'),
      txtFieldVal1 = txtField1.value,
      txtFieldVal2 = txtField2.value;

  if (squareNumCbx.checked) {
    if (txtFieldVal1) {
      txtField2.value = txtFieldVal1 * txtFieldVal1;
    } else if (txtFieldVal2) {
      txtField1.value = Math.sqrt(txtFieldVal2);
    }
  }
}
```

The next thing you may want to consider is what you want to happen if the user has a number in both fields.

Comment: Your answer still will not work You talked about better variable names and you are using the string as a textbox.

Comment: Yeah I had a typo from find+replace on the variable names. Changed Math.square to some gobbldy gook. Fixed that.

Comment: Error is still there

Comment: Now? Looks like find and replace screwed me in two places (the id for the checkbox too)

Comment: Still have a bug. :) `txtFieldVal2.value`

Comment: Found. What I get for posting w/o testing and finding my typos. Works now.